# where to add my websocket code in javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am very new to javaScript, I know some basics but have not yet completely understood the complete logics behind it (so far I have only worked with Python and a little bit of VBA)

For uni I have to build a browser interface to record audio and transfer it to a server where a Speech to text application runs. I found some opensource code here (https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/media/web-dictaphone/scripts/app.js) which I wanted to use, but is missing the websocket part. Now I don't know, where exactly to insert that. So far I have this:

code of the Webdictaphone:

```
// set up basic variables for app

const record = document.querySelector('.record');
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
const soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');
const canvas = document.querySelector('.visualizer');
const mainSection = document.querySelector('.main-controls');

// disable stop button while not recording

stop.disabled = true;

// visualiser setup - create web audio api context and canvas

let audioCtx;
const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//main block for doing the audio recording

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  console.log('getUserMedia supported.');

  const constraints = { audio: true };
  let chunks = [];

  let onSuccess = function(stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    visualize(stream);

    record.onclick = function() {
      mediaRecorder.start();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder started");
      record.style.background = "red";

      stop.disabled = false;
      record.disabled = true;
    }

    stop.onclick = function() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder stopped");
      record.style.background = "";
      record.style.color = "";
      // mediaRecorder.requestData();

      stop.disabled = true;
      record.disabled = false;
    }

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

      const clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip?','My unnamed clip');

      const clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
      const clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
      const audio = document.createElement('audio');
      const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

      clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
      audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
      deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
      deleteButton.className = 'delete';

      if(clipName === null) {
        clipLabel.textContent = 'My unnamed clip';
      } else {
        clipLabel.textContent = clipName;
      }

      clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
      clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
      clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
      soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

      audio.controls = true;
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
      chunks = [];
      const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      audio.src = audioURL;
      console.log("recorder stopped");

      deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
        e.target.closest(".clip").remove();
      }

      clipLabel.onclick = function() {
        const existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
        const newClipName = prompt('Enter a new name for your sound clip?');
        if(newClipName === null) {
          clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
        } else {
          clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
        }
      }
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  }

  let onError = function(err) {
    console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}
```

websocket part (client side):

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Open the WebSocket connection and register event handlers.
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded done');
  const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8001/"); // temp moved to mediarecorder.onstop
  dataToBeSent = function (data) { 
    ws.send(data);
  };
  console.log('ws is defined');
  


})
```

Right now I just stacked both of the parts on top of each other, but this doesn't work, since, as I found out, you only can define and use variables (such as ws) within a block. This leads to an error that says that ws i not defined when I call the sending function within the if-statement.

I already tried to look for tutorials for hours but none that I found included this topic. I also tried moving the web socket part into the if statement, but that also did - unsurprisingly work, at least not in the way that I tried.

I feel like my problem lays in understanding how to define the websocket so I can call it within the if statement, or figure out a way to somehow get the audio somewhere where ws is considered to be defined. Unfortunately I just don't get behind it and already invested days which has become really frustrating.

I appreciate any help. If you have any ideas what I could change or move in the code  or maybe just know any tutorial that could help, I'd be really grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {` part

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8001/"); // temp moved to mediarecorder.onstop
dataToBeSent = function (data) {
  ws.send(data);
};

const record = document.querySelector(".record");
const stop = document.querySelector(".stop");
const soundClips = document.querySelector(".sound-clips");
const canvas = document.querySelector(".visualizer");
const mainSection = document.querySelector(".main-controls");

// disable stop button while not recording

stop.disabled = true;

// visualiser setup - create web audio api context and canvas

let audioCtx;
const canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//main block for doing the audio recording

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  console.log("getUserMedia supported.");

  const constraints = { audio: true };
  let chunks = [];

  let onSuccess = function (stream) {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    visualize(stream);

    record.onclick = function () {
      mediaRecorder.start();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder started");
      record.style.background = "red";

      stop.disabled = false;
      record.disabled = true;
    };

    stop.onclick = function () {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder stopped");
      record.style.background = "";
      record.style.color = "";
      // mediaRecorder.requestData();

      stop.disabled = true;
      record.disabled = false;
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function (e) {
      console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

      const clipName = prompt(
        "Enter a name for your sound clip?",
        "My unnamed clip"
      );

      const clipContainer = document.createElement("article");
      const clipLabel = document.createElement("p");
      const audio = document.createElement("audio");
      const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

      clipContainer.classList.add("clip");
      audio.setAttribute("controls", "");
      deleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
      deleteButton.className = "delete";

      if (clipName === null) {
        clipLabel.textContent = "My unnamed clip";
      } else {
        clipLabel.textContent = clipName;
      }

      clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
      clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
      clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
      soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

      audio.controls = true;
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
      chunks = [];
      const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      audio.src = audioURL;
      console.log("recorder stopped");

      deleteButton.onclick = function (e) {
        e.target.closest(".clip").remove();
      };

      clipLabel.onclick = function () {
        const existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
        const newClipName = prompt("Enter a new name for your sound clip?");
        if (newClipName === null) {
          clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
        } else {
          clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
        }
      };
    };

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    };
  };

  let onError = function (err) {
    console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);
} else {
  console.log("getUserMedia not supported on your browser!");
}
```